# Can get a few image's path from my database but asking more than 9 give me an internal server error

Tags: image, symfony, amazon-s3

I'm in a web developpement internship, i have to work on a project under symfony 3.2 but i wasn't train on symfony, anyway, i discovered it on my own during the last two weeks (cause the persons who were supposed to help me don't know symfony and haven't work on the project) and here i'm facing a problem that i don't understand, the website is a nearly social network, and i have to work on the showings of user's posts by criteria's, if i get only a few post, no problems, i have the data the image's and evrything i asked, if i don't set a limit (with setMaxResults() ) i get an internal server error.

So i want to get the profile's image from posts's authors, i get the posts that i want within all related informations (like author), i get them with a function in my postRepository. Then, in my controller, when i try to extract some information (like author's image's path), with the method: $author->getImage()->getSrc(); here, if i'd setted less than 9 results in my postRepository query, it work perfectly, but if i don't want to set a limit, or if i want to set a bigger limit than 9 i got an:"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

in my postRepository

```php
public function getLastFiveCommunityPosts($community) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
                   ->join('post.communities', 'comm') 
                   ->where('comm.id = :commu')
                   ->setParameter('commu', $community)
                   ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
                   //->setMaxResults(9) work perfectly
                   //->setMaxResults(25) don't work
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();
```

in my controller

```php
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                $author = $post->getAuthor();
                $img = $author->getImage();//->getSrc();!!!!!HERE IS MY PROBLEM!!!!!
                $test = (null !== $img)? true : false;//what i just tried to test if getImage() return a null object, and no, on all post it returns true.
                $reTest = (null !== $img->getSrc())? true : false;// and this make me have an internal server error(if i don't set a maxResult between 1 and 9) 
                $data[] = [
                    'community' => $community->getName(),
                    'postContent' => $post->getContent(), 
                    'postDate' => $post->getCreatedAt(), 
                    'authorFstName' => $author->getFirstName(),
                    'authorLstName' => $author->getLastName(),
                    'authorJob' => $author->getJob(),
                    'authorImg'=> $img
                ];
            }
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
```

the project is using sw3 bucket and i think images that i want are hosted in this bucket. maybe there is a correct method to get them massively?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show the error message? I think it is really possible that at least at the 10th records, Image object is null. So you got an error when trying to do getSrc() on a null object.

Comment: That's really a lot of code, and only a pretty broad description of the error. Can you reduce the code to the neccessary parts, and explain your problem further?

Comment: I'm gonna re-edit the post, So now i just tried to test the $author->getImage() using a condition, if it's null return false, if it's set return true, and they'd all returned true, as soon as i tried the same conditionnal with adding "->getSrc()" i got, as usual, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: I think i got a pist, there is some authors who get an object image within the src, i think they're old profiles related to a period were the images were stored locally, so instead of beeing null, my problem is that thooses old profiles don't have the getSrc() method cause they got the src in them (don't know how to explain it but the two objects are a little bit different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was that all of my image object wasn't the same (due to old version's remaining profile) i found this method to test the image object:

```php
$test = property_exists($img, 'src'); //return true if it's an old object with src relate on him, return false if it's an object with the ->getSrc() method
```

so if it returns true, i send $img, and if it's returning false, i send $img->getSrc()!!!   thanks a lot to JessGabriel you send me on the right way!